# Difference between Respected and Respectful?

Tags: difference

Is there a difference between "a **respected** man" and "a **respectful** man"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is a respected person, it means that the person gets special honor or appreciation from others

> "He was a respected politician"

If someone is respectful, it means that the person has/shows respect to others. But note that it'd take a preposition 'to.'

> "He is always respectful to his teacher"

There is one more! ***Respectable!*** It means 'worthy of respect.'

> "He was a respectable citizen; he was never indulged in vandalizing public properties."

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, a respected man is one who commands respect, that is; people respect him. But a respectful man is one who shows respect; he respects people.